# Apache vhost overriding config?

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have Apache installed on my VPS. It is hosting one site on it, lets call it demo.com (located in /var/www/html/demo.com), but I also have files in /var/www/html that I want to view by pointing my browser to the IP of the VPS. Currently it seems if I want to go to

```
http://vpsIP/demofile.php
```

it will 404, so I'm assuming it's looking in the vhost dir.

Here are some settings from my httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.demo.com
    ServerAlias demo.com *.demo.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/demo.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/demo.com">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Allowoverride all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I have to specify another vhost of the VPS's IP to be able to view the files I want to?

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding another vhost solves this problem. Duh.

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```